# Unable to Create Queues in Airflow Workers

Tags: queue, celery, airflow

I'm using this compose file to run Airflow with celery executor: [celery executor](https://github.com/marclamberti/airflow-materials-vm/blob/master/airflow/docker/docker-compose-CeleryExecutor.yml). There is a flower service too in the yaml file to monitor workers. I want to add queues to workers. When I run the docker-compose file as is it worked, and I could see the workers on flower's UI. When I changed command tag of worker service from "worker" to "worker -q worker_subdag, default" no worker seemed to run in flower's UI.

```
command: worker -q worker_subdag, default
```

I tried below commands too, but no luck:

```
airflow worker -q worker_subdag, default
airflow celery worker -q worker_subdag, default
celery worker -q worker_subdag, default
```

Comment: I don't see RabbitMQ in the compose file, what/where is your Celery broker?

Comment: Redis is used as a message broker, its service defined at top of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the queue using the the `-Q` flag in the command, set it in the environment section of your docker-compose:

```
 environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
      AIRFLOW__OPERATORS__DEFAULT_QUEUE: worker_subdag
```